# Xaml Binding to Commands

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to call a command when my mouse is over a toggle button.

I have the following code.

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=PushPinMouse}" />
</Trigger>
```

When I roll the mouse over, the hand shows. But when i roll the mouse over it doesn't hit my PushPinMouse method.. Why's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this.  A common pattern is to make an attached behavior which will listen to the event in question, and fire an event.

A good, simple implementation is demonstrated in this [CodeProject arcticle on the Cinch Framwork](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CinchII.aspx).  Look for the LifetimeEvent class implementation.  This provides an attached behavior which subscribes to the "Activated" event on a form.  You can just as easily make one that listens for IsMouseOver changes, and fires a command.

If you wrote that, you could then do:

```
<Button local:HoverBehavior.Hovering="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

You could use the `Behavior<T>` class in the Expression Blend SDK to implement this in a simpler manner, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Command` property of the button is not supposed to trigger a command. It's supposed to specify a command that will be triggered when the button is clicked. MSDN [says so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command.aspx) right away:

> Gets or sets the command to invoke when this button is pressed.

Comment: is there an Idea that I can call an command when the mouse hovers over?